# Why does the restful interface return the data that was added to the etag and lastModify tags?

Tags: angular, nginx, restful-url, etag, last-modified

Angular2 project after npm run build:
When I press F5 or refresh the page,or click the menu of the page, the page content has not changed.
I must clear all the history of the browser in order to see the latest page.
Often this happens on some page

> **my environment:**
>   $:uname -v ~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 18 10:38:55 UTC 2015
>
> IDE: webstorm
>
> package manager: gulp": "^3.8.32",
>
> **http server : nginx**
>
> Browser: 
>  Chrome : version 56.0.29
>  Firefox: version
>   51.0.0
>  
>  Language:TypeScript 1.8.10
>
> Node (for AoT issues): node --version = v6.9.0

There is a picture here showing the browser debug information when this happens.

**And i found the preview content is the main page (index.html ) of my project. The content of the response is the html souce code of index.html**

In the picture below. I see response header with Etag and last Modify time. But why when I refresh, did not go to the server to retrieve data. **What is the relationship between this problem and the nginx cache configuration?
And why the in the browser F12 ,we can see the response the index.html source code ?**
[image]
Caching is very useful, for example, we can set a cache for a picture, then the browser can use the local cache, which can improve the speed and save the network. But a request for a restful api should not be set to etag and last-modify, because by setting these, it will not be able to get the latest data from the server for a period of time, and it will always use the local cache. Is this nginx problem? Or in the back of the nginx real server? how to solve this problem?
**Looking forward to your help! Thank you very much!**